# How to add one more development certificates in developer portal (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate

I have already one development certificate in my developer portal from my Mac1, then i tried to add another one development certificate in developer portal from my Mac2. How to create this? Is it possible to do this?
Where to add this? please help me.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each account has only one development certificate. you cannot create more than 1 certificates due to limitation. If you need more certificates only option is,if it is company account(not an individual account) then you can invite your company team members to join and create developer accounts for free, then you can create individual certificate for each account

Answer (score 0):

You can use the certificate on many Mac but, unfortunately, you cannot create more than one certificate on your provisioning portal.